# GEE filterBounds returns Error: Invalid property type

Tags: shapefile, google-earth-engine, export

I'm new to GEE. I'm trying to export a shapefile of Google building footprints cliped to a area of interest but I keep geting an error in the filterBounds.

This returns de message:

> Error: Invalid property type: Property longitude_latitude has type
> Geometry. (Error code: 3)

Any thoughts of what could be happening?

````
//BUILDING FEATURE COLLECTION FOR MICROSOFT AND GOOGLE
var google_building = ee.FeatureCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings/v3/polygons');

//CLIP BUILDING WITH AOI
var google_clip=google_building.filterBounds(AOI)

//ADD BUILDING TO THE MAP
Map.addLayer(google_clip, {color: 'yellow'}, 'Google Buildings');

//SET MAP CENTER
Map.setCenter(18.42, -33.92, 14);

//EXPORT DATA TO GOOGLE DRIVE IN SHAPEFILE FORMAT
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: google_clip,
  description: 'google_clip',
  folder: 'GEE',
  fileFormat:'SHP',
}); ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the `longitude_latitude` property cannot be encoded into a shapefile, because it is an object (`{"type": Point, "coordinates":[lon,lat]}`). The solution is to set it to `null` so that it gets dropped (or use `selectors` to not export it). If you still want to keep the coordinates, you can keep them as separate properties. Here's a demonstration of all this:

```js
var test = ee.FeatureCollection('GOOGLE/Research/open-buildings/v3/polygons')
.filterBounds(AOI)
.map(function(f){
  var coords = ee.Geometry(f.get("longitude_latitude")).coordinates()
  return f.set({
    longitude: coords.get(0),
    latitude: coords.get(1),
    longitude_latitude:null,
  })
})
```

and here's a small live working demo: https://code.earthengine.google.com/d0923f9ae036891a78d3f8ba708f4805

Comment: That worked well!! Thank you!!